# Using Text Files To Create Corresponding Print Statements To An Input

Tags: python, input, text-files

My issue is that I want to create a program that takes an input from a user and then from a text file, gets a response that corresponds to whatever the user put in. For example if the user put in "my SIM card isn't working" the program would respond by saying "buy a new sim card".
I could also do this with arrays aswell and I have started trying to create something with these arrays.

```
problems = ["My battery isn't working","My sim isn't working","My screen is cracked"]
solutions = ["Buy a new battery","Call your service provider","Contact the manufacturer"]
issue = input("What is the issue with your phone? ")
if (issue == problems[0])
    print(solutions[0])
```

and so on. But I would really like to incorporate text files as that would make my code more sophisticated.

Comment: One problem you may have thought about is `the customer will sometimes not input a string that you can process`. This could be due to spelling.

Comment: That can be fixed quite quickly but my main issue is what I have described. I would like to know how I can incoporate text files into the code

Comment: You have to use regex, with this module, your program will be better

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know how to read a text file?  You could put your problem/answer pairs in a text file, and split them as you read line by line.  use problem as key and answer as value in a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to save your data to the text file, then read and evaluate it. I would replace the arrays with a dictionary, because it fits your purpose better.

So first, saving the dictionary into a text file:

```
path = 'dict.txt'
solutions = {
    "My battery isn't working": "Buy a new battery",
    "My sim isn't working": "Call your service provider",
    "My screen is cracked": "Contact the manufacturer"
}
openFile = open(path, 'wt')
openFile.write(repr(solutions))
openFile.close()
```

Then, loading it, evaluating and using in your code:

```
path = 'dict.txt'
openFile = open(path, 'rt')
stringDict = openFile.read()
openFile.close()

solutions = eval(stringDict)
issue = input("What is the issue with your phone? ")
print(solutions[issue])
```

Using the `repr` and `eval` functions is maybe the easier way to go, but it would be better to dump and load the dictionary in JSON format, using python's standard [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library or any 3rd party library such as [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).

Comment: Using `simplejson`  instead of an `eval` would be better